Okta sending GET request and return 404 'Not Found'
Below is a controller method to get okta profile.I am getting 404 error (see below) when sending GET request(To Get Okta Profile Attribute). Response return 404 'not found'. Any thing I should rewrite on this line ?  //var response = await
client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
private async Task<OktaUserProfile?> GetOktaUserProfile(string userId)
{
    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

    var baseUrl = _configuration["Okta:Domain"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUrl))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Okta domain is not configured.");
    }

    // Ensure base URL starts with https://
    if (!baseUrl.StartsWith("https://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        baseUrl = "https://" + baseUrl.TrimStart('/');
    }

    var requestUrl = $"{baseUrl}/api/v1/users/{userId}?expand=blocks";
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("SSWS", _configuration["Okta:ApiToken"]);
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    try
    {
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Okta user profile response: {json}");
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OktaUserProfile>(json);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Failed to fetch Okta user profile. StatusCode: {response.StatusCode}, ReasonPhrase: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while fetching the Okta user profile. Please check the URL and network connectivity.");
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "An unexpected error occurred while fetching the Okta user profile.");
        return null;
    }
}


    {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:}


For the error 404 you are getting to resolve you could try these possible ways:
1)Make sure the userId is correct and exists in Okta.2) The Okta:Domain is correctly configured.3)API token is valid and has the right permissions.
4)Log the final URL to verify it’s correct, and test it manually. sample url : /api/v1/users/{userId} 5)Enable logging Log the full response body for additional error details.
